# Tags [substr], [substring], and [substrings] should be merged

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

[substr](/questions/tagged/substr), [substring](/questions/tagged/substring), and [substrings](/questions/tagged/substrings) all have the same idea. I think they should be merged.

Comment: `substrings` is more concept-y (kind of combinations, prefixes / suffixes whatever), while `substr` and `substring` look like they're being used as actual function names used in certain languages and not the concept - so, I'm not sure on this one...

Comment: @JonClements I don't know about here, but on Drupal Answers tags that represent a concept and tags that represent implementation of that concept aren't usually separated. Looking on [tag:substrings] I can't find any reason for it to stay separate. They know *concept*, they need *implementation*...

Comment: @JonClements I think they're functions in too many languages, thus eliminating any advantage of having separate tags.